# Difficulty using ordinary kriging in QGIS 3

Tags: layers, interpolation, qgis-3, kriging

I have a shapefile with 65 data points. Each data point has a value for NO2 pollution. I would like to use kriging to create a grid of NO2 pollution values  for the whole area. I have tried using Processing> Toolbox> SAGA> Ordinary Kriging. The process runs OK and two new layers are created called Quality Measure and Prediction, but both these layers are invisible or show no information.

What I assume is the value range of the Prediction file seems to indicate that something has gone wrong. It shows that the value of the black shade is 1.79769e+308 and the value of white is -1.79769e+308.

Can anyone help?

[image: screen grab of kriging results]

Comment: I think I see similar output working in QGIS3.0.1. If it is also your case, can you update to 3.0.2? It fixed my case.

Comment: I might try that. Not sure what else to do. The Ordinary Kriging process is now producing some visible output, but it's only in seemingly random patches.

Comment: Have you tried running the same process in the most recent long term release (2.18)? This would narrow down whether there's a bug in QGIS 3.0, or some problem with your data or method.